# Ignoring a second equals sign in a Powershell regular expression

Tags: powershell

I want to create the a regular expression to filter the lines in a bunch of text files.  Basically every symbol can be in the file, but I only need a specific set of lines containing info on connect direct.
The parameters of connect direct are always in the same type of form.
For example:

```
transfer.info=replace
file.location=\\adfs\work\department\building
```

I send it to an array of objects so I can create a .csv file with it.
The file contains a header of the first part (transfer.info;file.location)
and the values are stored in separate lines.

This works but I have one problem where there is an extra = sign in the value.
for example:

```
remote.job=cer.ext.ftm(recl=1500 block=4500)
```

I want as result that he puts the remote.job in the header, and that the rest behind de first = is put as value, and not an extra header recl like iet does now.

The code I have so far is this.

```
$csvobjecten = @()
$keyfiles = (dir "P:\APPS\D96_2903\ftkeys\AM\ACC" -recurse | where {$_.Name -match    "def$"}).FullName

foreach ($file in $keyfiles) {
$object = New-Object –TypeName PSObject
$object | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name KeyfileName –Value $file
$inhoud = get-content $file
foreach ($record in $inhoud) {
  if(($record -match "(.*)\=(.*)")) {
      $object | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name $matches[1] –Value $matches[2]
  }
}
$csvobjecten += $object
}
$csvobjecten | Export-Csv -delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation "c:\temp\keyfiles.csv"
```

The result is this header

```
KeyfileName;"Transfer.info";"File.Location";"remote.job=cer.ext.ftm(recl=1500 block";
```

Where I would like to have

```
KeyfileName;"Transfer.info";"File.Location";"remote.job";
```

and send the `cer.ext.ftm(recl=1500 block` part to the value of the header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two ways to ensure that the `=` matches on the first rather than the last occurrence in the string.

You could specify that the thing to left of the equals sign can't contain an equals sign:

```
([^=]*)=(.*)
```

Or you could do a non-greedy search for the thing to the left of the equals sign:

```
(.*?)=(.*)
```

Comment: By the way, @user3015037, I think you could have really simplified your question. It was full of irrelevant information that made it hard to work out what you were asking.

Comment: But I see a lot of questions where the complain is to little info,  so I guess I went overboard the other way.

Answer (score 2):

Use (.*?) in your first capture.  The ? makes it a "lazy" match, rather than "greedy".  It will stop as soon as it finds enough to satisfy the match.

```
$inhoud = 'remote.job=cer.ext.ftm(recl=1500 block=4500)'

$object = new-object psobject
foreach ($record in $inhoud) {
  if(($record -match "(.*?)\=(.*)")) {
      $object | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name $matches[1] –Value $matches[2]
      }
 }
 $object
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're using `.*` which matches anything, **as many times as possible**.

You want to use `.*?` which matches anything, **as few times as possible**

I think this regex might do what you need:

`(.*?)\=(.*)`